# Applying "checked" attribute to radio group using React state. It assigns, but checked input isn't getting styles applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a component with four radio inputs in a group. One of them is written as such:

```
<div className="answer3 col-sm">
              <label>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id="answer1"
                  name="answer"
                  value="A"
                  checked={this.state.selectedOption === "A"}
                  onChange={this.onValueChange}
                />
                <img src="./images/answer1.png" alt="answer A" />
              </label>
            </div>
```

The onChange method works to update the state, and I console log the input that is currently checked's value and it shows the value correctly. I have a style applied to radio buttons that are checked, basically changing the border, and it isn't being applied.
The style (just to test) is as such:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(117, 17, 17);
}
```

Is this because the "checked" attribute is being added dynamically, bypassing CSS's ability to apply styles appropriately?

Comment: Hi, this is not about react, radio inputs cannot be modified by CSS. You need to create your own custom radio input or use a ready one.
You can try easily by removing `:checked` from CSS and look at the result. There will still be no background-color on your radio input :)

Comment: I was able to remove the buttons from the radio inputs by using 

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
Are there just certain aspects of radio inputs that can't be modified?

Comment: I just ran a for loop on the four radio inputs to remove the specific class I'm trying to add and another for loop to add said class to the checked input. This happens when any answer is clicked. Not ideal, but it works and is decent with a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

it is not because of dynamic 'checked' attribute. just try to apply the radio button input style using `:after` pseudo class. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your React code seems to be okay... this is a CSS problem with radio button and its problem of accepting a background color change. What can be done with radio buttons is changing the `accent-color` from what I remember.

This is practically impossible and even if you were able to work something out, chances are it will work on some browsers and not on others.

But still, I think you can try something as simple as the one below.

```css
div {
  margin:10px;
}

.radio-btn:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="1" value="1" name="radbtn"/> <label for="1">Radio Option 1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="2" value="2" name="radbtn"/> <label for="2">Radio Option 2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="3" value="3" name="radbtn"/> <label for="3">Radio Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Take a look and see if it can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the computed style property and apply styles accordingly?
For instance

```js
<div className="answer3 col-sm">
  <label>
    <input
      className={value ?  'some-checked-class' : ''}
      type="radio"
      id="answer1"
      name="answer"
      value={value}
      checked={this.state.selectedOption === 'A'}
      onChange={this.onValueChange}
    />
    <img src="./images/answer1.png" alt="answer A" />
  </label>
</div>
```